# SQLite Database in Android library, Will it be shared among apps?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-library

I'm developing apps where few features are common in them, so I've created a library to put the common code at single point. I've SQLite database implemented in library.

My question is SQLite database of library will be shared by the apps ? 
I mean when insert X value from application A(using common library), will this data be also accessible from application B(using common library).

I think data won't be shared as each application will have their own storage and data will be saved in that storage only, still need clarification on this.

Comment: AFAIK you can not access other application private data from any other app

Comment: Yeah I've googled it and found that application does not share their data without making content providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL databases of each application is stored in their private folder on the storage. So the path would be as follow.

```
/data/data/[app_package_name]/databases/[database_name]
```

Applications cannot share data with each other using SQLite databases.

If we want data to get shared among other application we can use Content Providers.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html

Answer (score 0):

You can store data outside of the private application folder and access it from any app.

If you store data inside private application folder you can only share private data if you have same sharedUserId. Apps will have to be signed with same certificate for sharing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to share data between apps is to create a ContentProvider. It gives a similar interface to a DB, and can provide access restrictions via app permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ContentProviders` to share data from one app to another.For instance by creating a Content provider class in your application which can hold image metadata items. We will use a local SQLite database to store the data, but you can use any where you like to store the data.

First create an `ImagesProvider` class extending `ContentProvider` class and overriding the following methods.

```
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;


public class ImagesProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "androidcontentproviderdemo.androidcontentprovider.images";
    private static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/images");
    private static final int IMAGES = 1;
    private static final int IMAGE_ID = 2;
    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher = getUriMatcher();
    private static UriMatcher getUriMatcher() {
        UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "images", IMAGES);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "images/#", IMAGE_ID);
        return uriMatcher;
    }

    private ImageDatabase imageDataBase = null;

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case IMAGES:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.com.androidcontentproviderdemo.androidcontentprovider.provider.images";
            case IMAGE_ID:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.androidcontentproviderdemo.androidcontentprovider.provider.images";

        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        Context context = getContext();
        imageDataBase = new ImageDatabase(context);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        String id = null;
        if(uriMatcher.match(uri) == IMAGE_ID) {
            //Query is for one single image. Get the ID from the URI.
            id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
        }
        return imageDataBase.getImages(id, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        try {
            long id = imageDataBase.addNewImage(values);
            Uri returnUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);
            return returnUri;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        String id = null;
        if(uriMatcher.match(uri) == IMAGE_ID) {
            //Delete is for one single image. Get the ID from the URI.
            id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
        }

        return imageDataBase.deleteImages(id);
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        String id = null;
        if(uriMatcher.match(uri) == IMAGE_ID) {
            //Update is for one single image. Get the ID from the URI.
            id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
        }

        return imageDataBase.updateImages(id, values);
    }
}
```

To store the content we will need a database helper class for our content provider. Create an `ImageDataBase` class as follows

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ImageDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ImagesDatabase.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "imagestore";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
            " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, IMAGETITLE TEXT , IMAGEURL TEXT , IMAGEDESC TEXT )";

    private static final String SQL_DROP = "DROP TABLE IS EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME ;

    ImageDataBase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DROP);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Cursor getImages(String id, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder sqliteQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        sqliteQueryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);

        if(id != null) {
            sqliteQueryBuilder.appendWhere("_id" + " = " + id);
        }

        if(sortOrder == null || sortOrder == "") {
            sortOrder = "IMAGETITLE";
        }
        Cursor cursor = sqliteQueryBuilder.query(getReadableDatabase(),
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder);
        return cursor;
    }

    public long addNewImage(ContentValues values) throws SQLException {
        long id = getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME, "", values);
        if(id <=0 ) {
            throw new SQLException("Failed to add an image");
        }

        return id;
    }

    public int deleteImages(String id) {
        if(id == null) {
            return getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE_NAME, null , null);
        } else {
            return getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id=?", new String[]{id});
        }
    }

    public int updateImages(String id, ContentValues values) {
        if(id == null) {
            return getWritableDatabase().update(TABLE_NAME, values, null, null);
        } else {
            return getWritableDatabase().update(TABLE_NAME, values, "_id=?", new String[]{id});
        }
    }
}
```

**Declaring your content provider in the AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidcontentproviderdemo.androidcontentprovider">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <provider android:name="com.androidcontentproviderdemo.androidcontentprovider.ImagesProvider" android:authorities="androidcontentproviderdemo.androidcontentprovider.images">
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Using the content provider**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "androidcontentproviderdemo.androidcontentprovider.images";
    private static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/images");

    private ListView listView;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstViewImages);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                R.layout.list_layout,
                null,
                new String[] { "IMAGETITLE", "IMAGEURL", "IMAGEDESC"},
                new int[] { R.id.imgTitle , R.id.imgUrl, R.id.imgDesc }, 0);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        refreshValuesFromContentProvider();
    }

    private void refreshValuesFromContentProvider() {
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(), CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        Cursor c = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        adapter.swapCursor(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClickAddImage(View view) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("IMAGETITLE", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTxtImageTitle)).getText().toString());
        contentValues.put("IMAGEURL" , ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtImageUrl)).getText().toString());
        contentValues.put("IMAGEDESC", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtImageDesc)).getText().toString());
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        refreshValuesFromContentProvider();
    }
}
```